# PDO - best way to get row after insert into database

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I already know a method to get the row after insert. Something like:

```
//Right after insert into database
$id = $PDO->lastInsertId();
$lastrow = $PDO->query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=$id")->fetchObject();
```

However, I'm afraid this is not the best solution.
Is there any better method in this case?

Comment: This is the best solution

Comment: If you insert your data just before, you can use the data you have inserted instead of making a new request.

Comment: Try "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = (SELECT id FROM table WHERE id = LAST_INSERT_ID())"

Comment: @MarioLegenda LAST_INSERT_ID() has some drawbacks compared to lastInsertId(), thus latter one should be preferred

Comment: I did not know that. Could you give me some examples or links to articles?

Comment: @MarioLegenda https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-insert-id.html

Comment: While this is possible, it's rarely done. Please explain your scenario.

Comment: @YourCommonSense PDOs lastInsertId is calling LAST_INSERT_ID(). So i don't get why Mario's answer is wrong. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id

Comment: @mleko it is always a good idea to read the link you posted

Comment: @YourCommonSense can you tell what I'm missing? Copy paragraph for example. IMHO only flaw in Mario's query is unnecessary use of nested statement. `SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = LAST_INSERT_ID()` should do fine

Comment: @mleko if out of two inserts first one succeeded and second failed, and when called afterwards LAST_INSERT_ID() will return id for the first insert but mysql_insert_id will return 0

Comment: @YourCommonSense good point. But this raises question. Which of those two PDO use? PgSql for example don't have mysql_insert_id

Comment: @mleko it is using mysql API function

Answer (score 6):

It's apparently not the best as it doesn't utilize prepared statements

```
$id = $PDO->lastInsertId();
$stmt = $PDO->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=?");
$stmt->execute([$id]);
$lastrow = $stmt->fetchObject();
```

it have to be.

Yet there is not much sense in selecting the data you apparently have at hand already

Comment: There might be some auto generated field which you will fetch this way. Triggers are also possible.

Comment: This is not to suggest this answer is incorrect in any way, but a serious question if I may; if `$id` is returned from the result of the previous query and not from user input, why would it be preferential to parameterise this value for the second query?

Comment: @TheBlueDog  1. "if $id is returned from the result of the previous query and not from user input" is exact definition for the second order injection. 2. Despite of all injections, data you add into query have to be properly formatted. 3. Code tends to change. Developers tend to change. Database architecture tends to change. If you left your query insecure, by and by your application may grow up and separate these two queries. and then second will be used not only for the freshly selected data. 4. Why bother yourself with data source every time you run a query? Why not just one ONE simple rule

Comment: @YourCommonSense: That all makes perfect sense, thank you for the explanation.

Comment: @TheBlueDog I am glad you've got the point. This part is quite tricky, and one *can* argue over some points. But the root, the cornerstone of the 100% injection proof code is inviolable use of prepared statement with no exceptions. I was thinking over this matter for two years already and wrote an article, summing up all the experience and discussions I had. I'll be mighty grateful if you take time to read and give some feedback, especially on the things you disagree with. http://phpdelusions.net/sql_injection It's all right not to read though, just if you are curious.

Comment: @YourCommonSense: A very interesting and informative article, it's certainly made me realise just how little I really know about the subject.